# Match, eval and replace BBCode style tags

Tags: php, regex, replace, eval, bbcode

So in my PHP code I have a string like so;

```
The quick brown {{fox($a);}} jumped over the lazy {{dog($b);}}.
```

Now it might sound weird, but I want to go through the string, and collect all the BBCode style tags.

Then I want to `eval()` all the functions which are inside the `{{}}`'s. So I'd eval `fox($a);` and `dog($b);`.

Both of these functions return a string. And I want to replace the respective tags with the respective results. So supposing `fox()` returns "vulpes vulpes" and `dog()` returns "canis lupus", my original string would look like this;

```
The quick brown vulpes vulpes jumped over the lazy canis lupus.
```

However, I am famously terrible with regular expressions, and I have no idea how to go about this.

Any advice would be welcome!

(And yes, I am aware of the dangers of happy-go-lucky `eval()`ing. However, these strings come strictly from the developers and no user will ever be able to eval anything.)

Comment: your fortune preg_replace_callback

Comment: I read this question's title as "Match evil and replace."  Then saw that it said BBCode, and thought it was somewhat appropriate.

Comment: Robert, I approve of your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this with a regex, here's a solution that seemed to work for me:

```
function fox( $a) { return $a . 'fox!'; }
function dog( $b) { return $b . 'dog!'; }

$a = 'A'; $b = 'B';
$string = 'The quick brown {{fox($a);}} jumped over the lazy {{dog($b);}}.';
$regex  = '/{{([^}]+)+}}/e';
$result = preg_replace( $regex, '$1', $string);
```

The regex is pretty simple:

```
{{       // Match the opening two curly braces
([^}]+)+ // Match any character that is not a closing brace more than one time in a capturing group
}}       // Match the closing two curly braces
```

Of course, the `/e` modifier causes the replacement to be `eval`'d, producing this:

**Output:**

```
var_dump( $result);
// string(49) "The quick brown Afox! jumped over the lazy Bdog!."
```

Comment: I was wondering where exactly you eval'd it... thanks for clearing that up in your edit!

Comment: No problem `:)`. Whatever the capturing group captures (which in this case is `fox($a);` and `dog($b);`), those strings get `eval`'d.

Comment: Would the same thing work for non-functions? E.g. if I had `{{3 + 2;}}` or `{{$somevar;}}`, would those get eval'd and then displayed? Would I need to have `echo` within the tag?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out on my own. It does work, no `echo` necessary. And apparently even the semicolon is optional!

Comment: Okay I tried to do `{{foo('bar')}}` and now it's saying `Unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`. I guess it adds slashes to the `'`'s. Any fix for this? :) Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're only inserting valid php into those tags - you can just do a

```
$string = '.....';

$string = '?>' . $string;
$string = str_replace('{{', '<?php echo ', $string);
$string = str_replace('}}', '?>', $string);

ob_start();
eval($string);
$string = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Nice hack! However, would messing with the output buffer send headers? I'm doing this inside a CodeIgniter helper, and I don't suppose you're supposed to echo anything there yet.

Comment: Output buffers are nestable; if you start one output buffer when one is already started, your next close buffer command will only stop the most recent buffer.

Comment: So no, it won't send any headers.